# MSSQL 2005 - Server Service unable to start while installing

Tags: sql-server, sql

I am trying to install MSSQL 2005 Express on an VM running Windows Server 2012. I get to the point where it installs everything but fails to start the service.

I have tried checking the Log-On credentials (Originally network service, have tried Administrator account and the local account option) and starting the service from the command prompt.

Comment: `1.` Why are you installing a version of SQL that's 10 years old? `2.` Have you checked the installation log and the Event logs?

Comment: I am installing 2005 because I need to attach a database that is for 2005. I tried attaching it to 2014 but was unsuccessful.

Comment: What was unsuccessful? What errors did you encounter?

Comment: @joeqwerty It would not allow me to attach the databases. When attempting to attach them I selected them and clicked "attach". At that point it ran through them and each one popped up with the red X beside them. I assumed it was because of the version gap between 2005 and 2014.

Comment: The minimum database compatibility level for SQL Server 2014 is 100. SQL Server 2005 database compatibility level is 90. The attach process should have upgraded the database compatibility level to 100. Did you detach the SQL 2005 database or did you simply copy the files? Have a read here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189625.aspx

Comment: You might also want to try the backup/restore method. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty I did not detach nor copy them, they were downloaded.

Comment: as MDF and LDF files? Pardon me for saying this, but you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Ask the party that provided the files to perform a backup of the database and then download that, then restore it.

Comment: @joeqwerty There were no log files included as far as I can remember.

So If I have someone perform a database backup (on any version of SQL) they should be able to be restored into SQL2014 Express?